# PHP merge array by same value

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two big arrays with around 1000 keys and every day growing.
How can I merge this arrays into one by value in `array1[]['uid']` and `array2[][7]`

Please note that correct value could be for example `array1[45]['uid']` and `array2[155][7]` or
`array1[444]['uid']` and `array2[666][7]` etc.

```
array1
    0 => 
    array
      'login' => string '104' (length=5)
      'uid' => string '1363861889.100' (length=14)
    1 => 
    array
      'login' => string '131' (length=5)
      'uid' => string '1363863722.126' (length=14)
    etc...
```

and the other one

```
array2
     0 => 
    array
      0 => string '2013' (length=4)
      1 => string '03' (length=2)
      2 => string '25' (length=2)
      3 => string '15' (length=2)
      4 => string '39' (length=2)
      5 => string '49' (length=2)
      6 => string 'anonymous' (length=9)
      7 => string '1363863722.126' (length=19)
    1 => 
    array
      0 => string '2013' (length=4)
      1 => string '03' (length=2)
      2 => string '25' (length=2)
      3 => string '12' (length=2)
      4 => string '39' (length=2)
      5 => string '42' (length=2)
      6 => string 'anonymous' (length=9)
      7 => string '1363861889.100' (length=19)
    etc...
```

`array1[0]['uid']` has the same value here`array2[1][7]`
I would like get:

```
 array
      0 => string '2013' (length=4)
      1 => string '03' (length=2)
      2 => string '25' (length=2)
      3 => string '12' (length=2)
      4 => string '39' (length=2)
      5 => string '42' (length=2)
      6 => string 'anonymous' (length=9)
      7 => string '1363861889.100' (length=19)
      'login' => string '104' (length=5)
      'uid' => string '1363861889.100' (length=14)
```

Comment: this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array1_inverted = array();
foreach ($array1 as $subarray) {
  $array1_inverted[$subarray['uid']] = $subarray;
}
foreach ($array2 as &$element) {
  $array1_element = $array1_inverted[$element[7]];
  $element['uid'] = $array1_element['uid'];
  $element['login'] = $array1_element['login'];
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FpCivB)

Comment: It doesn't work as aspected. Keys uid and login are added but with no value

Comment: Fixed -- `$array1[$element[7]]` was supposed to be `$array1_inverted[$element[7]]`.

Comment: Great! :-) Nice coding skills you got there! I deleted my answer because I saw your one was much better.

Comment: After testing it `$array1_element` is the index value of `$array1`.  How can it returns any value in `$element['uid'] = $array1_element['uid'];`. I think it should be `$element['uid'] = $array1[$array1_element]['uid'];` Please suggest.

Comment: @SumitRaghav You're right, it doesn't work as I wrote. I've changed the first loop so that `$array1_inverted` holds the subarrays rather than the indexes. I've tested this and it works.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, It will also work. Thanks for the resolution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
  foreach($array2 as $value1)
  {
    if($value['uid'] == $value1[7])
  {
     $value1['uid'] = $value['uid'];
     $value1['login'] = $value['login'];
  }
 }
}
```

Try it meanwhile I wil think of some better alternative

Comment: See my answer for a non-Nsquared implementation.